# What is the output voltage of this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

My brain seems not working and has gotten intertwined with those resistors, resisting to think rationally to find the output voltage.

The source says it is

$$ Voutput = \frac {1}{2} Vinput$$

Why is the output voltage 1/2 of the input voltage? I cannot understand.

Comment: @Ghost Please show an attempt at a solution

Comment: Try redrawing the circuit in a sensible layout with the resistors all vertically oriented - you should soon see that one of them has no effect on Vout, and the reason for "Vout = (1/2)Vin" should become obvious.

Comment: You should try redrawing the schematic, then it might be more clear what is in series or parallel.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have been trying to solve this problem for 2 hours. Could not figure out where to start. I was thinking about the delta wye conversation. But that did not do any good.

Answer (score 4):

These problems can usually be made easier by re-drawing them.  Then, combine, transform, or remove components using the rules you've learned.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqzGuW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: should not the voltage be 1/Rp = (1/4 + 1/2)? That also does not satisfy the above claim.

Comment: What unit does dividing voltage by resistance give you?

Comment: It is 1333.33 ohms.

Comment: Ok, that's the parallel combination of the resistances.  You do not need this information to find Vo.

Comment: It some times become bloody confusing.

Comment: @vir The schematic would be ***still easier*** to understand if you would **stop** busing around the power supply wires. The whole thing turns into two very simple ***and completely independent*** branches if you do that. You didn't simplify enough, my opinion. Ground the bottom, label the tops. No wires. Power supply wires make a circuit look more complex than it is.

Comment: If I apply KVL I can find out the voltage which is 5. However, that was not my question. My question was why does the source say Vout = 1/2 Vin?

Comment: @Ghost You have two completely independent branches. You don't even need to worry about vir's R3. Just remove it and erase the wires to it. See what's left. That's all you need to see.

Comment: @Ghost: "My question was why does the source say Vout = 1/2 Vin?" - because you worked out that Vout is 5V and, as you surely already know, 5 is half of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep redrawing until it becomes obvious: -

[image]

Vout is clearly half of Vin.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is like this:

First eliminate this resistor because it's across a voltage source:

[image]

Then you can see that Vo(+) connects to Vi(+) and Vo(-) connects to the middle of the 2K resistors, which is at Vi/2, so the output voltage relative to Vi(-) is Vi - Vi/2 = Vi/2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVnDkL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>